# Yii CListView Ajax paginator + History Back

Tags: php, ajax, yii, browser-history

A controller **pages**, **ActionIndex** renders the page with the widget **CListView**
In the controller:

> public function actionIndex ()
>        {
>            model = new Pages ();
>            $ this-> render ('index', array (
>                'pages' => $ model,
>            ));
>        }

View Index:

> $ this-> widget ('zii.widgets.CListView', array (
>        'dataProvider' => $ dataProvider,
>            'viewData' => array ('switch' => true),
>            'enableHistory' => true,
>            'id' => 'pages_list',
>        'itemView' => '_view',
>            'template' => '{pager} 
>  {items} 
>  {pager}',
>        ));

Now the actual question:
In a ListView paginatore links look as follows:

> http:// localhost/pages/index/Pages_page/1/
>   http:// localhost/pages/index/Pages_page/2/
>   http:// localhost/pages/index/Pages_page/3/

But in the address bar as a link is inserted - that does not correctly. These are:

> Http:// localhost/pages/?/pages/index/Pages_page/3/=

And of course, do not flip over the page.
And if you re-move to any other page, the link is already in the form of:

> Http:// localhost/pages/?/pages/index//pages/index/Pages_page/3///ajax/pages_list/Pages_page/4/ =

As far as I understand it, it is necessary to pick the side settings are routed to URLManager'e.
just not sure what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller code has some mistakes.  Use the following for actionIndex().

```
/**
 * Lists all models.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Pages');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

I tested your view index.php code and it works fine.

Comment: controller working. I sealed. The problem with the link appears only after the EnableHistory

Answer (score 0):

If you disable enableHistory works fine. The real solution I don´t find it

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the

```
'id' => 'pages_list',
```

in view.